# Why does Sobel filter implementation not detecting the edges of the image correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to implement Sobel filter by using opencv. However, didn't get the expected edge detected image.

Used cv2.getDerivKernels() to get the respective kernels for x and y direction.  Then sepFilter2D() is used to apply the kernels to get the derivatives in x direction and in y direction separately. Then, magnitude of the derivative is found out and compared with the threshold to get the edge detected image.

The derivatives in x and y direction are plotted separately, which gave expected results. But the final result isn't the one that was expected. Please go through the code provided below.

There may be a problem with the threshold value as I took it as 200, but also tried with lesser values, still no good result. Not sure how to decide what threshold to take.

```
# Kernels for derivatives in x direction
kx1,kx2 = cv2.getDerivKernels(0,1,5)
img_x = cv2.sepFilter2D(image,ddepth=-1,kernelX=kx2,kernelY=kx1)

# Kernels for derivatives in y direction
ky1,ky2 = cv2.getDerivKernels(1,0,5)
img_y = cv2.sepFilter2D(image,ddepth=-1,kernelX=ky1,kernelY=ky2)

# Magnitude
magnitude = np.sqrt((img_x * img_x) + (img_y * img_y))
magnitude *= 255.0/np.max(magnitude)
mag = magnitude.astype("uint8")

# Compare with a threshold value
final_mag = np.zeros(mag.shape,dtype="uint8")
for i in range(mag.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mag.shape[1]):
         if mag[i,j]<200:
             final_mag[i,j] = 0
         else:
             final_mag[i,j] = 255
cv2.imshow("final_mag",final_mag)
```

Comment: Please be sure to include the necessary `import` statements and images so that your code is **Minimal Complete and Verifiable** as required by StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also, consider using the `cv2.threshold()` function for thresholding.

Comment: you might need individuwl thresholds or different regions in the image. Did you try canny edge detection or lineSegmentDetector instead?